# facebook picture type square

Tags: ios, facebook, image

I have some code that uses SLRequest to grab me info as well as the picture for a facebook user. The me info works no problem, and then I can successfully grab the picture with this URL:

```
NSURL *picture = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/{user id}/picture"];
```

But not this URL:

```
NSURL *picture = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/{user id}/picture?type=square"];
```

Why isn't the square version working? This is a valid type according to this page:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-pictures/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that should work.

You may want to try `https://graph.facebook.com/{user_id}?fields=picture.width(100).height(100)` instead, which returns the URL rather than actual JPEG data.

Comment: This is a great idea!  I will try this out when I circle back around to this issue.